# assigning range of lines to a variable in vimscript

Tags: vim

I'm looking for a more elegant way of doing this

```
function PasteBin() range
    let l:stdin = join(getline(a:firstline, a:lastline), "^M")
    let l:output = system("pb", l:stdin)
    echo l:output
endfunction
```

Specifically, how can I avoid using getline() and join()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you're just reinventing [:w_c](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/editing.txt.html#%3Aw_c).  If you already have a visual selection, you can just run

```
:'<,'>w !pb
```

to use the visual selection as the stdin for pb.

Comment: Thanks, that's a lot cleaner exactly what I was looking for.